# How to run multiple Sitecore 9.x Instances locally?

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

I've installed several Sitecore 9.0.2 (XP0) instances locally and went into some issues regarding certificates. I was wondering if anyone had the same issue and how it was solved?

Comment: You should at least tell us what the issues are..

Comment: If you are using SIF or SIF-LESS make sure that in the install script your prefixes are unique for each of your installs. Also, you can browse to look at your certs start > mmc > add snap in > certificates > local and make sure the certs look right. You also may need to check the thumbprint of the certs installed and make sure they match what is in the configs for sitecore and xconnect. And like @Gatogordo said..more details..the better for us to help out.

Comment: Do you have other Sitecore 9.0.x instances running on that same machine? If you are, my 2 cents are that you have self-trusted root certs without a private key and Sitecore 9.1 don't like this. There is also a mess about the store it uses during the install...

Comment: I've installed it with SIF and I'm getting exceptions when opening the Experience Analytics. One of the error messages are:
Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgentException: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableExceptionMessage: An error occurred while sending the request.Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web

Comment: With just a little bit of googling, I found this: https://robearlam.com/blog/sitecore-xconnect-xdbcollectionunavailableexception-urgh - again it describes thumbprints that don't match due to a bad installation. Also, are you sure you have the necessary collectionuser created? And as all others have said and have put this on hold, update your original post with details that craft a better question.